# Scraping wikipedia URLs through jsoup using keywords/macros

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm not sure what the best way to frame this question is but here goes:

I have a program that needs to do a keyword search on the web and looks for corresponding URLs and in particular the Wikipedia URLs to extract summary information from it. The question is - using jsoup, instead of giving the entire URL can I input information like this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/keyword where keyword is a user input and can be anything like Coffee, Hinduism, World War II etc.

Also how would I check if the corresponding link exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to connect to Wikipedia pages based off of a keyword input and get out a JSoup Document that you can apply JSoup to.

If that's the case, you could make a method that takes in a keyword parameter and returns the document from the Wikipedia page:

```
Document getWikiDocumentByKeyword(String keyword) throws Exception {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + keyword).get();

    return doc;
}
```

This will connect to the page for the given keyword and return the Document which you can do whatever you like with.

To address your second question, this method will throw an exception if it can't connect to the page for whatever reason (i.e. page doesn't exist).

You would then want to handle that exception in your call of the method somehow:

```
try{
    Document document = getWikiDocumentByKeyword("Coffee");
} catch(Exception ex){
    // Trouble connecting, handle the exception however you want.
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, for answering all my web scraping related queries :)

Comment: @serendipity no problem, I try my best!